# simple jQuery glitch regarding fadeIn/fadeOut effects for content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

**Scenario:** I have a Question which has 2 radio buttons & two subforms: `subformA` and `subformB`

When user checks the 1st radio button subformA should fadeIn elseif he checks 2nd radio button `subformB` should fadeIn.

**Problem:** I have done the code but the problem is when User checks the 1st radio button the subformA will appear & if incase he changes his mind and clicks another option instead of previous one. The subformB gets concatenated to subformA.

**Request:** I want to make those forms mutual Exclusive (no concatenation effect should occur if user rechooses his selection of radio button). Its a small thing that I am unable to notice. Thanks!

**my js code:**:

```
<!-- script for the Div -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#subafform').hide();
 $("#element_4_1").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#subafform').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#subafform').fadeOut();
    }
    });
    });

</script>
```

Other parts of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#subbform').hide();
 $("#element_4_2").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#subbform').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#subbform').fadeOut();
    }
    });
    });

</script>




 <li id="li_4" >
  <label class="description" for="element_4">Are you affiliated with Company? </label>
  <span>
   <input id="element_4_1" name="element_4" class="element radio required" type="radio" value="1" />
   <label class="choice" for="element_4_1">Yes</label>
   <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4" class="element radio required" type="radio" value="2" />
   <label class="choice" for="element_4_2">No</label>

  </span> 
  </li> 






<li id="subafform">
  <ul>
  <li id="li_5_1" >
  <label class="description" for="element_5_1">Department/College </label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_5_1" name="element_5_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div> 
  </li>  <li id="li_5_2" >
  <label class="description" for="element_5_2">Department Chair </label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_5_2" name="element_5_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div> 
  </li>  



</li>



<li id="subbform>

........

....

</li>
```

Comment: Both conditions show the #subafform, can you please provide some html of your forms?

Comment: If you could post an example of your form and radio markup, it would be easier to realize what you're talking about.

Comment: Its the `js` of just one `subform` the other subform has same lines of code except for `elementid` and `subform name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone clicks and already checked radio button, it will just remain checked. So your if else statement isn't really doing you any good. What I would do is have form B always fadeout when you click A, and form A always fadeout when you click B. Something simple like this:

```
$("#element_4_1").click(function() {
    $('#subafform').fadeIn();
    $('#subbfform').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you specify why `display: none;` is placed in CSS? I am not gettign that part of it.

Comment: I just added that so that when the page loads, the user won't see the form. Previously you were doing this with `$('#subafform').hide()`. All the hide function does is to set the CSS display propety to none.

Answer (score 3):

**Example DOM:**

```
<form class="subform" id="subforma">
    <button>Form A</button>
</form>

<form class="subform" id="subformb">
    <button>Form B</button>
</form>

<form id="switcher">
    <input type="radio" name="show_form" value="subforma"> Show Form A<br />
    <input type="radio" name="show_form" value="subformb"> Show Form B<br />
</form>
```

**Example JQuery:**

```
$('input[name="show_form"]').click(function(){
    var form_id = this.value;
    $('.subform:visible').fadeOut();
    $('#' + form_id).fadeIn();
});
```

**Example CSS:**

```
.subform {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#switcher {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/hFax3/

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is checking if an individual radio button is clicked, and then checking if it's selected or not. Well, since the user clicked on a radio button of course it's going to be selected.

What you need to do is remove that `if` statement, and just have it so that when button A is clicked, fade subformA in and subformB out. If jQuery is clever (I doubt it...) it won't fade out subformB if it's already faded out, so there's no problem.

Similarly, when button B is clicked, fade subformB in and subformA out.